# Can I use useCallback only, or memo only or both?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading React Docs about `useCallback` and `memo` and got a little confused if I had to use both at the same time in the example below from their docs.

Starter code:

```
function ProductPage({ productId, referrer, theme }) {
  // ...
  return (
    <div className={theme}>
      <ShippingForm onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </div>
);
```

From the code above, toggling the `theme` prop freezes the app for a moment, but if you remove `<ShippingForm />` from the JSX, it feels fast. Therefore, we'll have to optimize the `ShippingForm` component because by default, when a component re-renders, React re-renders all of its children recursively. So, to solve the problem we can tell `ShippingForm` to skip re-rendering when its props are the same as on last render by wrapping it in `memo` as below:

```
import { memo } from 'react';

    const ShippingForm = memo(function ShippingForm({ onSubmit }) {
      // ...
});
```

However, if the `handleSubmit` function is an arrow function or a regular function using the function keyword as below, the `memo` optimization won’t work because in JavaScript, a
`function () {}` or `() => {}` always creates a different function, similar to how the `{}` object literal always creates a new object. Hence, the `ShippingForm` props will never be the same, and the `memo` optimization won’t work.

The code below will not work

```
function ProductPage({ productId, referrer, theme }) {
  // Every time the theme changes, this will be a different function...
  function handleSubmit(orderDetails) {
    post('/product/' + productId + '/buy', {
      referrer,
      orderDetails,
    });
  }
  
  return (
    <div className={theme}>
      {/* ... so ShippingForm's props will never be the same, and it will re-render every time */}
      <ShippingForm onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this also will not work

```
 function ProductPage({ productId, referrer, theme }) {
  // Every time the theme changes, this will be a different function...
  const handleSubmit = (orderDetails)=> {
    post('/product/' + productId + '/buy', {
      referrer,
      orderDetails,
    });
  }
  
  return (
    <div className={theme}>
      {/* ... so ShippingForm's props will never be the same, and it will re-render every time */}
      <ShippingForm onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

So, to solve the issue we'll have to use the `useCallback` hook as below.

Now my question is since we're using the `useCallback` hook do we still keep telling `ShippingForm` to skip re-rendering when its props are the same as on last render by wrapping it in `memo`? Or it's unnecessary?
Thanks for helping.

```
function ProductPage({ productId, referrer, theme }) {
  // Tell React to cache your function between re-renders...
  const handleSubmit = useCallback((orderDetails) => {
    post('/product/' + productId + '/buy', {
      referrer,
      orderDetails,
    });
  }, [productId, referrer]); // ...so as long as these dependencies don't change...

  return (
    <div className={theme}>
      {/* ...ShippingForm will receive the same props and can skip re-rendering */}
      <ShippingForm onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi ITselect! Go through the answer to the linked thread and let us know. We will consider reopening your question if you think it doesn't answer it.

Comment: @Youssouf Oumar It doesn't answer my question. If you read carefully, my question is that in the code I provided, when using the useCallback hook, should I continue to use the useMemo hook to wrap ShippingForm in memo? Basically, can we use useCallback and useMemo together or using only the useCallback will get rid of the need to use the useMemo hook? Please read my question carefully. Thanks!

Comment: Your last and second-to-last snippet seem identical. "*And this also will not work: [code]*" seems inaccurate, what am I missing?

Comment: Your title asks about the `useMemo` hook, your question body however only refers to the `memo` function that wraps components.

Comment: @Bergi you're correct. I fixed the second to last to the correct one. Thanks

Comment: Hi @ITselect! I took quite some time to write a long detailed answer. Check it out and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use both.

P.S.
You have a little mistake in your question: useMemo is a hook for memoizing values inside component (like useCallback but it saves result of function execution). React.memo is almost same stuff but for Components itself. You are asking about last thing.

Comment: @ITselect: Re: "I'm not asking about React.memo. There's no mistake here'": This is not true. Your question literally states, "Now my question is do we still keep telling ShippingForm to skip re-rendering when its props are the same as on last render by wrapping it in `memo`?"; so either you *are* asking about `memo`, or you made a mistake when you claimed that you were.

Comment: @ruakh  I think you and Alexey are very correct. I missed the point when reading the React Docs. They indeed were referring to memo and not useMemo. So, I changed my title to update it with memo instead of useMemo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the confusion is coming from the fact you are assuming a component renders when receiving different props. Actually, a component only renders when its internal state changes or when its parent renders (because its internal state has changed), as you can read on the [doc](https://react.dev/learn/render-and-commit#step-1-trigger-a-render):

> There are two reasons for a component to render:
>
> 1. It’s the component’s initial render.
> 2. The component’s (or one of its ancestors’) state has been updated.

This is why, this `Child` component with no props, gets called again when its parent renders:

```js
const Child = () => {
  console.log("Child with no props renders");
  return <div></div>;
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);

  console.clear();
  console.log("Parent renders");
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setState((prev) => !prev)}>Render parent</button>
      <Child />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

When this behavior is problematic, because `Child` does lots of computing, for example, you could tell React with the help of `memo` to render it only when it receives new props:

```js
const MemoziedChild = React.memo(() => {
  console.log("MemoziedChild with no props renders");
  return <div></div>;
});

const Parent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);

  console.clear();
  console.log("Parent renders");
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setState((prev) => !prev)}>Render parent</button>
      <MemoziedChild />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

`memo` compares the previous props with the new one (while rendering `Parent`). If it's the same, it skips rendering `Child`. This would work whether you are not passing any props like the above or primitive ones. However, if you pass an object or a function defined in the body of `Parent`, they get passed down with different memory references, hence we use `useCallback` to memoize functions, and `useMemo` to memoize objects:

```js
const ChildWithPrimitiveProp = React.memo(() => {
  console.log("ChildWithPrimitiveProps renders");
  return <div></div>;
});

const ChildWithNonMemoizedFunctionProp = React.memo(() => {
  console.log("ChildWithNonMemoizedFunctionProp renders");
  return <div></div>;
});

const ChildWithNonMemoizedObjectProp = React.memo(() => {
  console.log("ChildWithNonMemoizedObjectProp renders");
  return <div></div>;
});

const ChildWithMemoizedFunctionProp = React.memo(() => {
  console.log("ChildWithMemoizedFunctionProp renders");
  return <div></div>;
});

const ChildWithMemoizedObjectProp = React.memo(() => {
  console.log("ChildWithMemoizedObjectProp renders");
  return <div></div>;
});

const Parent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);
  
  function fn(){};
  const obj = {};
  
  const memoizedFn = React.useCallback(fn, []);
  const memoizedObj = React.useMemo(()=>obj, []);
  
  console.clear();
  console.log("Parent renders");
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setState((prev) => !prev)}>Render parent</button>
      <ChildWithPrimitiveProp message="Hello World" />
      <ChildWithNonMemoizedFunctionProp fn ={fn}/>
      <ChildWithNonMemoizedObjectProp fn ={obj}/>
      <ChildWithMemoizedFunctionProp fn ={memoizedFn}/>
      <ChildWithMemoizedObjectProp fn ={memoizedObj}/>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

So you need both or one of them, depending on your use case. Also, it's worth knowing that rendering doesn't mean DOM update, which is done in [the commit phase](https://react.dev/learn/render-and-commit#step-3-react-commits-changes-to-the-dom).

Comment: React Doc reads 'With this change, ShippingForm will skip re-rendering if all of its props are the same as on the last render. This is when caching a function becomes important!' So, yes ShippingForm component will re-render if its props change.

Comment: React check the props when there is a memo involved while rendering. But the actual cause is due to the parent rendering. Have you tried the examples I have given? Also, have you checked my latest edit?